# How does 'ssh <destination> exit' terminate the session?

Tags: ssh, command

In a command like `ssh <destination> true`, ssh executes the command `true` on the destination then terminates the session. When running `ssh <destination> exit`, what initiates the termination of the session? Is it the ssh program itself like in the other command, or is it the `exit` command itself that the destination executes?

The SSH manual says, `The session terminates when the command or shell on the remote machine exits and all X11 and TCP connections have been closed.`

Comment: ssh will pass whatever extra `command` arguments (joined by spaces) to the login shell of the user on the remote machine via its `-c` option. Assuming that the login shell is `/bin/sh`, `ssh host exit` will run `/bin/sh -c exit`, `ssh host exit 1` will run `/bin/sh -c 'exit 1'`, etc. Is there something more subtle to your question that I'm not able to figure out?

Comment: @UncleBilly I'm just curious about the mechanics of ending the session.

Comment: And using `exit` or `true` as the command makes no difference to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exit` executed by the remote shell would terminate that shell.  In the case when `true` is executed, the remote shell would terminate due to not having any further commands to execute, but `exit` would terminate it even if there were further commands afterwards (as in any script).

In the simple case where the SSH session is *only* for executing a set of commands (where it does not set up tunnels or use connection sharing), the session would terminate when the remote shell terminates, no matter *how* the remote shell terminates (either by `exit` or by some error, or receiving a `HUP` signal, or by simply reaching the end of the script).

Note that the manual says "[...] and all X11 and TCP connections have been closed". This means that the *connection* may not terminate just because the remote *shell* has terminated.  This will be the case when you, for example, are using connection sharing with `ssh -M` and `ssh -S` (or the `ControlMaster` setting in `~/.ssh/config`; see `man ssh` and `man ssh_config`).  I assume that SSH tunnels would also keep the SSH session alive until they are explicitly closed.

To truly terminate the SSH connection, you may send the `exit` *control command* using `ssh -O exit user@host`. This would terminate all shared SSH sessions to `user@host`.

Comment: I can see that it does terminate from `exit` when I compare `ssh host "echo here; exit"` and `ssh host "exit; echo here"`.